# Servo Motor set up

Tags: motor, wiring, servo, setup

I want a servo motor to move/rotate a set distance and hold position (bear weight:which for my uses would be minimal) and then when power isn't applied/cut-off it drives back to original position. I'm trying to do this with a minimal amount of equipment. How could I go about doing this?

Comment: If power is cut-off, how can you expect it to "drive back to the original position". Even with springs to pull it back, stiction will make a significant error. You need power to drive it back accurately.

Comment: @Andyaka  The original position can be defined by a mechanical stop.

Comment: @NickAlexeev my comment is a challenge to the OP to think about what he's saying in terms of "no power" and "accuracy".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Braking a DC brushed motor](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16654/braking-a-dc-brushed-motor)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more like an application for a pneumatic or hydraulic actuator than a servo motor. A bleed valve could open when power is lost, allowing the load to return to the original position, under gravity, in a controlled way.

Having said that, if the load isn't too heavy, you might be able to use *electrical braking*. For more details than I can provide, see [Russell McMahon's excellent answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/16666/3774) to [Braking a DC brushed motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16654)